# jQ Conditional handling of several separated events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

Is there a way to handle separated events by one condition, without checking it in every event handler function? I.e. in the code listed below. Or maybe there is a way to do it more convinient? Any thoughts/suggestions?

```js
var Obj = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.initialized = true;
  $(document).on('click', function(){
    if(self.initialized){
      alert('hax!');
      self.initialized = false;
     }
  })
  $('input').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    if(self.initialized){
      $(this).attr('class', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hovered' : '');
    }
  })
  /*$('...').on(...) etc etc*/
}
var obj = new Obj()
```

```css
.hovered{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Click me!'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've played a bit around and maybe this is a working solution for you:

```
eventHandlerWrapper = function(state, callback) {
        return function(e) { 
        if(state.initialized) {
            return callback.bind(this, e)();
        }
    }
}
var Obj = function() {
  this.initialized = true;
}
var obj = new Obj()

$(document).on('click', eventHandlerWrapper(obj, function(e){
    obj.initialized = false;
}))

$('input').on('mouseenter mouseleave', eventHandlerWrapper(obj, function(e){
  $(e.currentTarget).attr('class', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hovered' : '');
}))
```

I've also create a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jz17L7h6/

Comment: Hmm, this one can be a solution for the problem. If there will not be any better answer, i'll pick yours `=)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another class for your button?

```
var Obj = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.initialized = true;  
    self.dom = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val('Click me!')
        .data('obj', this)
        .appendTo($('.container'));
    /*$('...').on(...) etc etc*/
}

$(document)
  .on('click', 'input:not(.uninitialized)', function(){
    alert('hax!');
    $(this).addClass('uninitialized')
      .data('obj').initialized = false;
  })
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'input:not(.uninitialized)', function(e){
    $(this).attr('class', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hovered' : '');
  });

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Obj();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/fzez5th2/3/

If you can't add a class, you can turn off your listeners

```
var Obj = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.initialized = true;    
    self.dom = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val('Click me!')
        .appendTo($('.container'));

    var moveHandler = function(e){
        $(this).attr('class', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hovered' : '');
    }; 
    var clickHandler = function(){
        alert('hax!');
        self.initialized = false;
        self.dom
            .off('mouseenter mouseleave', moveHandler)
            .off('click', clickHandler);
    };

    self.dom
        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', moveHandler)
        .on('click', clickHandler);

    /*$('...').on(...) etc etc*/
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Obj();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/fzez5th2/4/

Or you can override your handlers

```
var Obj = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.initialized = true;    
    self.dom = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val('Click me!')
        .appendTo($('.container'));

    self.moveHandler = function(e){
        $(this).attr('class', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hovered' : '');
    }; 
    self.clickHandler = function(e){
        alert('hax!');
        self.initialized = false;
        self.clickHandler = function (e) {};
        self.moveHandler = function (e) {};
    };

    self.dom
        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) { self.moveHandler.apply(this, arguments); })
        .on('click', function (e) { self.clickHandler(e); });

    /*$('...').on(...) etc etc*/
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Obj();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/fzez5th2/5/

**Update**

I think you need to separate mouse events handlers.

```
var Obj = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.initialized = true;    
    self.dom = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val('Click me!')
        .appendTo($('.container'));

    var handlers = {
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            $(this).addClass('hovered');
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
        }
    }

    var moveHandler = function(e){
        handlers[e.type].apply(this, arguments);
    }; 

    var clickHandler = function(e){
        alert('hax!');
        self.initialized = false;
        clickHandler = function (e) {};
        moveHandler = function (e) {};
    };

    self.dom
        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) { 
            moveHandler.apply(this, arguments); 
        })
        .on('click', function (e) { 
            clickHandler(e); 
        });

    /*$('...').on(...) etc etc*/
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Obj();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/fzez5th2/7/

Comment: In the inital example he wants this behavior on different Elements, your fiddles aims on one Element.